# Search bar in table in wordpress

Tags: search, table

I used this code in the table plugin. It checks data through only one column, I want the code to use all columns.

```
const searchFun = () => {
let filter = document.getElementById('myInput').value.toUpperCase();
let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
let tr = myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

    if (td) {
        let textvlaue = td.textContent || td.innerHTML;
        if (textvlaue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Even if it's in your Wordpress site, this looks like a javscript question that isn't related specifically to Wordpress. You might want to make your code render correctly in your question, and try a site specifically for javascript questions.